# Azure SQL Server Auditing EventHub Bicep

Tags: azure, azure-sql-database, azure-resource-manager, azure-bicep

I am trying to replicate the following settings in Bicep:
[image][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/feMfZ.png)

When I manually add and inspect the ARM for a guide, there is nothing in there other than:

```
{
        "type": "Microsoft.Sql/servers/auditingSettings",
        "apiVersion": "2022-08-01-preview",
        "name": "[concat(parameters('sqlServer'), '/Default')]",
        "dependsOn": [
            "[resourceId('Microsoft.Sql/servers', parameters('sqlServer'))]"
        ],
        "properties": {
            "retentionDays": 0,
            "auditActionsAndGroups": [
                "SUCCESSFUL_DATABASE_AUTHENTICATION_GROUP",
                "FAILED_DATABASE_AUTHENTICATION_GROUP",
                "BATCH_COMPLETED_GROUP"
            ],
            "isAzureMonitorTargetEnabled": true,
            "isManagedIdentityInUse": false,
            "state": "Enabled",
            "storageAccountSubscriptionId": "00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000"
        }
```

This refers only to a storage account, which I haven't set up and the Sub ID of 0000 is what is presented, not my masking.

Reviewing this [Microsoft article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/templates/microsoft.sql/servers/auditingsettings?pivots=deployment-language-bicep) on the API, there are no properties to set the Event Hub, only a storage account. Is this possible therefore via IaC?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To configure `eventhub` or `log analytics`, don't specify the `storageAccountSubscriptionId` property:

```bicep
param sqlServerName string = ''

// Get a reference to sql server
resource sqlServer 'Microsoft.Sql/servers@2020-11-01-preview' existing =  {
  name: sqlServerName
}

// Enable SQL Server auditing
resource enableSqlAuditing 'Microsoft.Sql/servers/auditingSettings@2021-02-01-preview' = {
  name: 'auditing'
  parent: sqlServer
  properties: {
    isAzureMonitorTargetEnabled: true
    state: 'Enabled'
    auditActionsAndGroups: [
      'SUCCESSFUL_DATABASE_AUTHENTICATION_GROUP'
      'FAILED_DATABASE_AUTHENTICATION_GROUP'
      'BATCH_COMPLETED_GROUP'
    ]
  }
}
```

Then you can send `SQLSecurityAuditEvents` using diagnostic settings:

```bicep
resource masterDb 'Microsoft.Sql/servers/databases@2020-08-01-preview' existing = {
  name: 'master'
  parent: sqlServer
}

// Create diagnostic settings
resource SqlSecurityAuditLogs 'Microsoft.Insights/diagnosticSettings@2017-05-01-preview' = {
  scope: masterDb
  name: 'SQLSecurityAuditLogs'
  properties: {
    eventHubName: '...'
    eventHubAuthorizationRuleId: '...'
    logs: [
      {
        category: 'SQLSecurityAuditEvents'
        enabled: true
        ...
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Comment: Many thanks Thomas. Quick question - on our Prod environment SQL Auditing to Log Analytics is already enabled, meaning the above code doesn't set the event hub. It only configures the event hub is the sql auditing is disabled. What would you suggest in this scenario?

Comment: do you need both eventhub and log analytics ?

Comment: The LA are for are central monitoring. The EVNS are so we can export logs to QRadar

Comment: It's baffling two can be configured via the portal, yet there isn't a way via IaC

Comment: you can configure diagnostic settings for LA and eventhub through IaC. Not sure whats the issue here ?

Comment: If I use the code supplied Thomas against a SQL Server that already has LA set up, then then EVNS is never applied. If however I disable the SQL Audit and LA, the IaC will apply just the EVNS. It appear that the code will do one or the other, not both

Comment: if you specify the `workspaceId` as well on the diagnostic settings, it should send the logs to both (See [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/templates/microsoft.insights/diagnosticsettings?pivots=deployment-language-bicep#diagnosticsettings-1))

Comment: This is the API that sets the SQL Audit `Microsoft.Sql/servers/auditingSettings` if LA is already setup, then EV isn't selected. Yes `Microsoft.Insights/diagnosticSettings` will configure the necessary diagnostics, but will they be exported via SQL Auditing to the event hub as the option isn't selected in SQL Auditing?

Comment: I think the UI is confusing: it was designed for old settings, with unified diangostic settings, you shoud not be specify anything in the auditingSettings => you just wanna enable them then diagnosticSettings  should do the trick for all your needs